# Messenger Bot in NodeJS - Get Started Button Has No Color

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, facebook-messenger

I use `createGetStarted()` in the `app.listen()` method and it appears and the action works properly but the button is just blue hoverable text on top of a white button, no border. Basically **just a text link, not a button**. What could be the problem?

I have this method to call the appropriate API:

```
function callThreadSettingsAPI(data) { //Thread Reference API
request({
uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings',
qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
method: 'POST',
json: data

}, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  console.log("Thread Settings successfully changed!");
} else {
  console.error("Failed calling Thread Reference API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
}
});  
}
```

This method creates the json:

```
function createGetStarted() {
var data = {
setting_type: "call_to_actions",
thread_state: "new_thread",
call_to_actions:[
 {
  payload:"getStarted"
}
]
};
callThreadSettingsAPI(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The appearance of the button will vary depending on the device and software used to access Facebook, for example Chrome on a computer or the Messenger app on iPhone.

Chrome on Windows:

[image: Get started in Chrome on Windows]

Messenger app on iPhone:

[image: Get started on iPhone]

Comment: Lol, didn't consider this possibility for some reason... thank you.